# Calculate the parameters of the diode in accordance with the circuit diagram

Tags: diodes

I was given a task at the university:

In the presented circuit diagram, the volt-ampere characteristic of the diode is approximated by the ratio shown below.

How to define the following parameters:

1. Determine the voltage and current of the diode at the operating point
2. Determine the differential resistance of the diode.
3. Determine the effective value of the output voltage vO.

Since I don't really understand electronics, I don't understand what to do with an alternating voltage source in this case. Please help me find these parameters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For homework questions we expect you to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve the problem yourself. Show us all of your work. Tell us how much you **do** understand about the problem. Then you can ask a **specific** question.

Comment: Begin to solve the problem with DC (Q1). The schematic will be "simplified" ... Then, we can resolve (after) the AC questions (Q2 and Q3).

Comment: To solve Q1 graphically, try plotting the "load line" and "diode curve" in the same graph.

Comment: Read this first, only first part https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_line_(electronics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the principle of the "load line", and the curve i(v) of the diode.

Here is a Maple sheet that calculates the Quiet Point.

[image]

And here, one can find the Dynamic DC simulation of finding the QP.

[image]

And here is the graphical construction of QP, where one can read also the value of the dynamic impedance of the "diode".

[image]

And here is the TRansient analysis showing the output voltage ...

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for a very detailed answer, you helped me very well to understand what is happening on this scheme.

Comment: Have you read and understood the "load line" principle

Comment: I read a few more lectures and sort of finally figured it out)